# Unable to load template (Smarty)

Tags: php, templates, smarty3

I have this code

```
{extends "`$root`public\included_template\user\user_index_structure.tpl"}
```

where $root is https://www.scoa.org/SCOA/ is my site but i got a error saying that

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template 'https://www.scoa.org/SCOA/public/included_template/user/user_index_structure.tpl' in .....
```

i tried

```
.../../../SCOA/ and /SCOA/
```

but nothing works, is there way to include or extends a file from a document root ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to use full path

{extends "/var/www/yourfullpath/public/included_template/user/user_index_structure.tpl"}

Thats example for linux.

You can`t load template from URL